# Slick2D smooth movement of object with cursor keys

Tags: java, slick2d

I'm playing around with Slick2D and I'm running into a problem when trying to move a simple rectangle with the cursor keys.

Functionality wise, the code works. However, if you keep one of the cursor keys pressed, every now and then there is a little hick-up in the movement wen looking at the screen.

Can anyone suggest a code improvement to make the rectangle move smoothly?

Here is the test code I used:

```
public class SlickGame extends BasicGame {
// ==================================================================================
// Fields
// ==================================================================================
private Rectangle mPlayer;

// ==================================================================================
// Constructor
// ==================================================================================
public SlickGame() {
    super("SlickGame");
}

// ===========================================================
// Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
// ===========================================================
@Override
public void init(GameContainer pGameContainer) throws SlickException {
    // create the player centered on the screen
    mPlayer = new Rectangle(pGameContainer.getWidth()/2 - 20, pGameContainer.getHeight()/2 - 20, 40, 40);
}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer pGameContainer, int pDelta) throws SlickException {
    Input input = pGameContainer.getInput();
    int speed = 200;
    float distance = speed * ((float)pDelta/1000);

    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)) {
        mPlayer.setX(mPlayer.getX() - distance);
    }
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)) {
        mPlayer.setX(mPlayer.getX() + distance);
    }
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)) {
        mPlayer.setY(mPlayer.getY() - distance);
    }
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)) {
        mPlayer.setY(mPlayer.getY() + distance);
    }
}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer pGameContainer, Graphics pGraphics) throws SlickException {
    pGraphics.fill(mPlayer);
}

// ==================================================================================
// Methods
// ==================================================================================
public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
         // create the game's container app
         AppGameContainer container = new AppGameContainer(new SlickGame());
         // adjust the resolution and disable fullscreen
         container.setDisplayMode(800, 600, false);
         // specify desired FPS
         container.setTargetFrameRate(60);
         // start the game
         container.start();
     }
     catch (SlickException e ) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
}
```

Comment: After trying a bit more, I notice that removing the line container.setTargetFrameRate(60); gives an improvement. Is this the right way to do it? Any other ideas?

Comment: well, i didn't understand, is it a problem, that movement itself lags or that image looks distorted. If the problem is latter, then removing `container.setTargetFrameRate(60);` alone doesn't fix this, but together with `container.setVSync(true);` it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, naughty_hacker. Adding `container.setVSync(true);` did the trick.